# Using Grep and BBEdit/Textwrangler to copy a set variable and paste it earlier in the line

Tags: html, grep, textwrangler, bbedit

I have a long HTML document with a list of 10-digit text variables that I'd like to copy and paste into a link earlier in the line, for example:

```
<a href="example.com/">1234567890</a>
```

Into:

```
<a href="example.com/1234567890">1234567890</a>
```

So, a Grep pattern that finds the 10-digit variable, then copies and pastes it either 2 characters before it, or identifies the incomplete href and pastes it at the end of it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regex, use a proper XML/HTML parser.

Check: [Using regular expressions with HTML tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

You can use one of the following :

    xmllint
    xmlstarlet
    saxon-lint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your input data always that consistent? (link/number/closing link)?

In that case, your 'find' can be (in textwrangler's syntax)

```
(.*)">(\d{10})</a>
```

and your replace

```
\1\2">\2</a>
```

\1 matches everything before the ">

\2 matches your 10 digit number

Comment: Thank you! What I ended up doing was putting: 

<a href="example.com/(.*)">(.*)</a>,

in the find area and:

<a href="example.com/\1">\2</a>,

in the replace box.